# login with different user level

Tags: php, mysql, session

I tried make 1 form to make login with different user level, so i tried to login with correct user and password (user level and admin level) then it redirect me to http://localhost/dashboard/ (when it suppose direct to index.html if level user or direct to index.php if level admin) but when i tried input wrong username and password it succeed redirect to index.php.

here's my code :

```
session_start();

include "koneksi.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * from user WHERE log_usr='$username' AND pas_usr='$password'");
$exitCount=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($exitCount==1){
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $id = $row['log_usr'];
            $lvl = $row['sts_usr'];

            if ($lvl=='A')
            {
                $link = '../index.html';
            }
            elseif($lvl='U')
            {
                $link = '../index.php';
            }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header ('location:".$link.'');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Username dan Password tidak valid.'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
    }
```

Comment: solved by delete "/" on variable link, but if else not working, it direct straight to index.php (user level or admin level), it is my if else wrong ?

Comment: a) don't pass variables directly into your query, use parameterized statements instead - just imagine someone using the username `';DROP TABLE user; -- ` b) don't ever EVER EVER store passwords as plain text. hash them. use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for this.

Comment: thats sql injection ? thx for advise i will learn how to make my website more secure..

Comment: that is one very simple example for SQL injection, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note of the `Keywords` that shouldn't be used as `column names` unless you use backticks.

```
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * from user WHERE log_usr='$username' AND pas_usr='$password'");
```

**Should be:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * from `user` WHERE log_usr='$username' AND pas_usr='$password'");
```

**For the list of `Keywords` and `Reserved Words`, check here:**

[10.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

**And in your `ELSE` condition:**

```
else{
    echo "<script>alert('Username dan Password tidak valid.'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
}
```

You still redirect them to `index.php` even though the inputs are invalid?

Comment: its direct to index.php without session, if login they will login index.php with user session or admin session

Comment: user on $query is table, i select all from table name user, it working fine without backticks, i tried use backtick like you said and its says mysqli_num_rows() expect parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean given in line 12, line 12 is query variable ($query)

Comment: Please post screenshot of your table.

Comment: here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcIk9mNMrwoTkxlVzhBMHRqTW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You sure you used `backtick` and not `single quote`?

Comment: see my comment above on my question its solved but still got error again, if else for variable link not working

Comment: `header ('location:".$link.'');` should be `header ("location:'.$link.'");`

Answer (score 0):

i just realize use variable row to get user and password data, even though i already make variable data for fetching user and password from db thats why if else never work because it didnt get value user and password then straight to elseif condition.

```
session_start();

include "koneksi.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * from user WHERE log_usr='$username' AND pas_usr='$password'");
$exitCount=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($exitCount==1){
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $id = $data["log_usr"];
            $lvl = $data["sts_usr"];

            if ($lvl=="A")
            {
                $link = 'index.html';
            }
            elseif($lvl="U")
            {
                $link = 'index.php';
            }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        echo $link;
        header ("location:$link");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Username dan Password tidak valid.'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
    }
```